# how to cover the default value set inside the function

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to change the default value of fout each time I calling for the function replacing it by the value of fout I got from  at the end of for loop last time

What I tried is shown below, I set the default value of fout to be zero, but failed to change the default value each time I call the function

```
Rolltwicethenstop <- function(sc, btt, sh, dout, dsel, dleft, porder)
{ 
  fout<-0
  for (i in 1:3)
  {
    if(dout[i]=="F")
    {
      fout=fout+1
    }
  }  
  if(fout+(13-length(dleft))>=6&btt>0)
  {
    return(FALSE)
  }else if(fout+(13-length(dleft))>=6&&btt>0&&sh>0)
  {
   return(FALSE)
  }else
  {
    return(TRUE)
  }
}
```

the start value of fout is 0 for the first time I call for the function, if there are two "F"s in the dout ,then at then end of for loop fout=2.I expect to use fout=2 as the start value for the second time I call for the function, and add up all the "F"s I got in total from all rounds in the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your assignments of the `fout` variable to `<<-`, this sets the variable to the global environment, then before you start, set `fout <- 0` at the start.

```
fout <- 0

Rolltwicethenstop <- function(sc, btt, sh, dout, dsel, dleft, porder)
{ 
  for (i in 1:3)
  {
    if(dout[i]=="F")
    {
      fout<<-fout+1
    }
  }  
  if(fout+(13-length(dleft))>=6&btt>0)
  {
    return(FALSE)
  }else if(fout+(13-length(dleft))>=6&&btt>0&&sh>0)
  {
    return(FALSE)
  }else
  {
    return(TRUE)
  }
}
```

**More explanation**

At the moment, when you call your function, you set the `fout` variable to 0. This is a problem as each time you call the function, you will set it to 0. So we move this outside the function.

The next problem is when you add 1 to the `fout` variable, this is only defined within the environment of the function, so we change that by assigning the variable to the `global environment`.

Read more about environments and scope [here](https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/environment-scope/).

**Alternative method1**

I am not sure about your specific framework, but a different approach is to add the `fout` variable as an argument in your original function such that,

```
Rolltwicethenstop <- function(fout, sc, btt, sh, dout, dsel, dleft, porder)
```

and return the variable fout, along with the other values, for example, change all return functions to this,

```
return(list(logic = FALSE, fout = fout))
```

This should work for most purposes.

**Alternative method2**

Another method would be reading and writing a file every time the variable `fout` is called/defined,

For example,

First create a file with value 0, called `fout`,

```
write.csv(0, "fout")
```

This will create a file in the location,

```
getwd()
```

Then you can read the value back using the following,

```
read.csv("fout")[1,2]
```

So edit your function to read and write these files.

For multiple players, add an argument called `player.name`, then instead of calling the file `'fout'`, call it `paste0(fout, player.name)`.

Comment: are there any other methods without using global variables? I need to run several functions at a time, it will produce something wrong if all functions share same the global variable

Comment: Yes, does my explanation of the Alternative method work for you?

Comment: it works for one function but if i wanted to apply it to many player functions running together it doesn't work since the fout value from the former players will add up to the other player functions running after it

Comment: Sure, so I have added a second alt method, where instead of defining a global variable, you write a file. But to answer your question, when you have different players, just call the `fout` variable a different name, for example, `fout1` for player 1, `fout2` for player 2 etc... This will require additional arguments to tell your function which player is which.

Comment: @XingqiFei If my answer has answered your question, consider accepting the answer, the tick to the left at the top. If I haven't, please let me know how it can be improved.

Comment: the argument porder means the order of player which can use as player.name you stated above, but additional argument is not allowed for this assignment

Comment: In that case, you can use the `porder` argument to change the name of each `fout` variable? May be easiest, but slower, to just write a file, like I detailed in Alt method 2? and instead of player.name, use porder?